# Skype4Java check what a user says in chat

Tags: java, skype4java

Well, I need Skype4Java to check what a user has said in chat, so if it equals a command then it will send a response. I have the response part handled, I just need to know how to make it check what a user has said in chat.

Comment: Please tell us, what have you tried.

Comment: I tried a few things, all resulted in errors. Any tips on checking what someone sends to you in chat?

Comment: your question seems very low quality, please add your research and avoid asking opinions here

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
Skype.addChatMessageListener(new ChatHandler());
```

And:

```
public void chatMessageReceived(ChatMessage chatMessage) throws SkypeException {
    User sender = chatMessage.getSender();
    sender.send("hue" + sender.getId());
}
```